# react-bootstrap and dynamic menu

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm new to react and trying to do a dynamic menu with the help of some JSON. But I have a problem with level 2. Is there not a better way to do this?
And can I check if a level 1 has any level 2 or not. Because if there is not any Level 2 i need to use `NavItem`. If there is I need to use `NavDropdown`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import { Nav, Navbar, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Style.css';
import Logo from '../Logo'

// MockData
var MockData = [
    {
            "text": "Donorsøgninge",
            "id": "1",
            "parentid": "-1"
    }, {
            "id": "2",
            "parentid": "1",
            "text": "Hot Chocolate"
    }, {
            "id": "3",
            "parentid": "1",
            "text": "Peppermint Hot Chocolate"
    }, {
            "id": "4",
            "parentid": "1",
            "text": "Salted Caramel Hot Chocolate"
    }, {
            "id": "5",
            "parentid": "1",
            "text": "White Hot Chocolate"
    }, {
            "id": "6",
            "text": "Donorsæd",
            "parentid": "-1"
    }, {
            "id": "7",
            "parentid": "6",
            "text": "Caffe Americano"
    }, {
            "id": "8",
            "text": "Caffe Latte",
            "parentid": "6"
    }, {
            "id": "9",
            "text": "Caffe Mocha",
            "parentid": "6"
    }, {
            "id": "10",
            "text": "Cappuccino",
            "parentid": "6"
    }, {
            "id": "11",
            "text": "Pumpkin Spice Latte",
            "parentid": "6"
    }, {
            "id": "12",
            "text": "Bliv donor",
            "parentid": "-1"
    }, {
            "id": "13",
            "text": "Caffe Vanilla Frappuccino",
            "parentid": "12"
    }, {
            "id": "15",
            "text": "450 calories",
            "parentid": "13"
    }, {
            "id": "16",
            "text": "16g fat",
            "parentid": "13"
    }, {
            "id": "17",
            "text": "13g protein",
            "parentid": "13"
    }, {
            "id": "14",
            "text": "Caffe Vanilla Frappuccino Light",
            "parentid": "12"
    }, {
        "id": "18",
        "text": "Services",
        "parentid": "-1"    
    }, {
          "id": "19",
          "text": "Om os",
          "parentid": "-1"  
  }, {
        "id": "20",
        "text": "Info",
        "parentid": "-1"    
}]


export default class Test extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.navId = '';

        this.state = {
      showSubMenu: []
        };
    }


  render() {

    let showNavFirstlevel = MockData.filter(
      (firstLevel) => {
                this.navId = firstLevel.id; 
                return firstLevel.parentid === "-1";
      }
        )

    return (

      <Navbar>
        <Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Brand>
                      <Link to='/' className="navbar-brand"><Logo/></Link>
          </Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar.Header>
        <Nav>

          { showNavFirstlevel.map((firstLevel) => (
                    <NavDropdown eventKey={firstLevel.id} key={firstLevel.id} title={firstLevel.text} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                          <Submenu navId={firstLevel.id}/>
                        </NavDropdown >
                    ))}

        </Nav>
      </Navbar>

        );  
    }

}





class Submenu extends React.Component {
  render() {

    let showNavSecondlevel = MockData.filter(
      (secondLevel) => {            
                return secondLevel.parentid === this.props.navId;
      }
    )

    return (

      <div>
              { showNavSecondlevel.map((secondLevel) => (
          <MenuItem key={secondLevel.id} eventKey={secondLevel.id}>{secondLevel.text}</MenuItem>
              ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: It looks like your brackets are out of balance.  You've got an open '{' before this.state.showSubMenu, but I don't see a close for it.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Thank you.